# Unable to read hidden field value from server side

Tags: javascript, asp.net, postback

I have a aspx page (default.aspx), inside which I am loading a user control (tree.ascx).

inside the tree.ascx there is a hidden field.

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="server"/>
```

I am assigning a value to the hidden field using javascript.

```
document.getElementById('<%=HiddenField1.ClientID%>').value = "some text here";
alert(document.getElementById('<%=HiddenField1.ClientID%>').value);
document.getElementById('form1').submit();
```

The alert displays the value absolutely fine. which means the value gets inserted in the hidden field properly.

But when I am posting back to server and checking the value, it is always null.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            // do something.
        }
        else
        {                
            string str = this.HiddenField1.Value;              
        }
    }
```

My code is always getting a empty string here. somehow the postback is erasing the value from the hidden field.

What could be the reason?

Comment: Don't you have any more code in Page_Load except that if else?..
Because if you get data for hidden field from db or something else, it'll(HiddenField.Value) be overwritten

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using below syntax. It works for me even after postback.

ASPX code

```
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="aspHiddenField" />
<input type="hidden" id="inputHidden" value='<%= aspHiddenField.ClientID %>' />
```

JavaScript Code

```
var inputHidden = document.getElementById('inputHidden');
$("#" + inputHidden.value).val("some text");
```

Code Behind

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(aspHiddenField.Value))
 {
//Your code goes here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if your control is within a master page, if it is, then you need to access it like that, 1st Master Page->within master page look for the control's value, it will work surely.

Answer (score 0):

Place your hidden field in update panel   like :

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpnlHidden" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>
<asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="server"/>
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

This will work for you :-)